# Prove $S = \{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$ is closed under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am really bad at proofs so please bear with me and help me better understand. Thank you.
This is what I had, but my teacher said I needed more. I know I need something, but I am unsure what that something is.

> Let $a^2,b^2 \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then $a^2+b^2 = c^2\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus S is closed under addition.

Comment: Your S is $[0, \infty)$

Comment: You need probably to say it works because every non-negative real number has a square root.

Comment: The "more" that you need is some appropriate level of justification for why such a $c$ exists.

Comment: Yeah.  $a^2, b^2 \in \mathbb R$ so $a^2 + b^2 = M \in \mathbb R$.  But how do we know that there is a $c \in \mathbb R$ so that $c^2 =M$?  Otherwise you just seem to be claiming it is true by fiat.  Consider these.  Let $S = \{5n + 1|n\in \mathbb Z\}$.  Prove it is closed under addition. Pf: Let $5a + 1, 5b+1\in \mathbb Z$.  Then $(5a+1) + (5b+1) = 5c + 1\in \mathbb N$. Thus it is closed under addition.  Do you see why that is *not* a valid proof?  Is your proof any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take two arbitrary elements of your set $S$, add them together, and show that the result still belongs to $S$. The condition that a number belongs to $S$ is that we can express it as the square of a real number.

Choose $a,b\in S$. Since these are in $S$, we know that they're of the forms $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now we add them together, so
$$a+b=x^2+y^2\geq0.$$

I can assert that this sum is greater than or equal to 0 because it's the sum of two squares, and a square is always non negative. This implies that we can take the square root of this sum, or in other words, if we let $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$ we have that
$$a+b=r^2$$.

We just expressed the sum of our arbitrary elements as the square of a real number. This means that $a+b\in S$ and $S$ is closed under addition.

Comment: r would be in the set R correct since x,y are in R?

Comment: While true that $r$ is in the set (it has to be, it’s positive so we can take its square root), the point is that $r^2$ is the square of some real number, so $r^2$ is in $S$. But we defined $r^2=a+b$, so for arbitrary $a,b$ in $S$ we’ve shown that their sum $a+b$ is also in $S$. This is the property that $S$ is closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing *every* non-negative real number is a square and the non-negative real numbers are closed under addition.

It'd actually be fairly hard to show that if $m$ has a square root and $n$ has a square root then $m + n$ has a square root directly with the properties of squares and roots.

But If $x \ge 0$ then $\sqrt x$ exists.  SO $x \in S$.  If $x < 0$ then $\sqrt{x}$ does not exist.  So $x \in S \iff x \ge 0$.  SO $S=[0,\infty)$.

And if $m,n \in S$ then $m\ge 0; n\ge 0$ and $m+n \ge 0$.  So $m+ n \in S$.

That's all.  (ALthough it's.... to be honest... a bit of a dishonest problem.)